# Accessing an element of an array of a dynamic class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, dynamic

I have a dynamic class, which has an array declared normally, **before** runtime.

Usually, you can dynamically access a variable, whether it has been declared or not with

```
myClass["variable"] = 4;
```

however, trying to do this with an array, like so

```
myClass["array[0]"] = 4;
```

does not store 4 into the first element of array, and instead stores it into the variable "array[0]".

For instance, after executing the previous code,

```
trace(myClass.array[0]);
```

traces undefined, where as

```
trace(myClass["array[0]"]);
```

traces 4.

Is there anyway I can access the elements of the array dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think of it as evaluating a String. It's still just a chain of properties.

So the practical answer to your question is:

```
var o:Object = {};
o["array"] = [];   //we do have to insantiate the array first
o["array"][0] = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks - that does what I want.